# iteration on complex dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below, as you see I am trying to print `key_p` which is not in dictionary. I want to check if my `key_p` exist in dictionary, print the value and when the `key_p` is not in dictionary print `0`.

When I put condition `elif`, it will print two times `0` (= the number of element in the dictionary) but I just want to check only `key_p`, meaning if the `key_p` is in the dictionary print `1` if only `key_p` is not in the dictionary print `0`.

```
sc_dict = [('fl', {'ab': 1}), ('fl', {'abel': 1})]

key_p = "tep"

for row in sc_dict:

 sc = row[1]

for field, values in sc.items():

   if field == key_p:

      print("1")

   elif field != key_p:

      print("0")
```

Comment: `sc_dict` is a list, not a dictionary. Therefore it cannot have keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
sc_dict=[('fl', {'ab': 1}), ('fl', {'abel': 1})]

key_p="tep"

dict_part = [sc[1] for sc in sc_dict]

together = {}

for item in dict_part:
    together.update(item)

print(together.get(key_p, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `sc_dict` is a list, not a dictionary.

Judging by your code, I understand your question as follows: out of the dictionaries inside the tuples held by `sc_dict`, you want to check whether any holds a specific key.

Here's one way, using the `any` builtin function (which returns a boolean, which we convert to an `int` according to your requirements) and tuple unpacking:

```
>>> sc_list = [('fl', {'ab': 1}), ('fl', {'abel': 1})]
>>> key = 'key_p'
>>> int(any(key in d for _, d in sc_list))
0
>>> key = 'abel'
>>> int(any(key in d for _, d in sc_list))
1
```

Depending on what your actual problem is, it might be beneficial to construct a `ChainMap` from your dictionaries. The following example introduces the concept and also solves the original question.

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> cm = ChainMap(*(d for _, d in sc_list))
>>> cm
ChainMap({'ab': 1}, {'abel': 1})
>>> int('key_p' in cm)
0
>>> int('abel' in cm)
1
```

Comment: FYI to anyone: [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) is a Python 3 only construct.